# How to resize images in Silverlight 4?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Doing something like this doesn't work.

```
foreach (Image img in Canvas1.Children.OfType<Image>())
        {
            double h = img.Height / 2;
            double w = img.Width / 2;
            img.Height = h;
            img.Width = w;
            img.UpdateLayout();
            Canvas1.UpdateLayout(); 
        }
```

Must I transform the BitmapImage which I assign to the Image with some kind
of Transform-class or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested changing the size of images and it worked for me:

```
foreach (var item in _grid.Children.OfType<Image>())
{
    item.Width = 400; // Update calls are unnecessary
}
```

One thing that might be wrong with your code is that you access `Image.Height`/`Width` without setting it first. If those properties are not set they are on `Auto` (which is `Double.NaN`), if you want to retrieve the current values which are calculated by the layout system use [`ActualHeight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualheight%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)/[`Width`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualwidth%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).